# Is there a Regex expression to match every that is not in quotations

Tags: javascript, regex, matching

I'm working on a Regular Expression that looks at everything except information in quotations. An example would be:

`Lorem ipsum "dolor" sit amet, "consectetur" adipiscing elit.`

Would change to

`Lorem ipsum sit amet, adipiscing elit`

I've already tried

`.*(?=".*").*`

and

`[^"].*[^"]

neither worked so I'd appreciate help.

Comment: Use `replace` i.e. `str.replace(/"[^"]*"\s*/, "")`

Comment: Or, `s.split(/\s*"[^"]*"\s*/).join(" ").trim()`

Answer (score 0):

Heres a way ...

```js
var str = `Lorem ipsum "dolor" sit amet, "consectetur" adipiscing elit.`

console.log(str.replace(/\"[a-z]{1,}\"/g, ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something in the line of this. It handles the case where the sentence starts or ends with a quotation mark.

```js
var str = '"Lorem" ipsum "dolor" sit amet, "consectetur", adipiscing "elit."';
var regExp = /(?:^|\W)(\".+?\")(?:\W|$)/g;
var res = str.replace(regExp, " ").trim();
console.log(res);
```

RegExp explained:

`(?:^|\W)` - non capturing group of either start of the string or just a space (technically a "non word character" - could be a punctuation, a bracket, etc)

`(\".+?\")` - anything between `"` (including the quotation marks themselves)

`(?:\W|$)` - same as the first one, but checking for the end of a string instead

`g` flag - check for all occurrences of a matching pattern

Answer (score 0):

Try this , non-greedy `(".*?")` match two quotations and as few as possible between them.

```js
var a ='Lorem ipsum "dolor" sit amet, "consectetur" adipiscing elit.';
console.log(a.replace(/".*?"/g,''));
```

Answer (score 0):

*I hope to help you :*

```
/[,\w]+(?![^" ]*")/g
```

```js
var str = 'Lorem ipsum "dolor" sit amet, "consectetur" adipiscing elit.' ;
var res = '' ;
var patt = /[,\w]+(?![^" ]*")/g ;

while ( (arr = patt.exec(str)) != null) { res += arr[0] + ' ' ; }

console.log( res ) ;
```